# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403 in angular 4 & spring boot (RestAPI) application

Tags: java, spring, angular, rest, spring-boot

I am creating application with front-end using Angular-4 and backend using spring boot(RestAPI),JPA,MySQL DataBase.
I am **successfully able to retrieve/get** stored data from backend to frontend, but **while posting the data** from frontend to backend getting an error as :
"*Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403*".

---

code snippet for frontend Angular code :

```
myFoo(productData : Product) : Observable<any>{

   let headers = new Headers();
     headers.append( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
     let myOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this._http
      .post("http://localhost:8081/..(URI)../productslist",productData,myOptions)
      .map( (resp : Response) => resp.json() )

}
```

where productData passed from Controller class into above method argument is of Object type:

```
productData : any =  {
      price: 3500,
      productavaliabledate: "March 13, 2018",
      productcode: "GND-124",
      productid: 6,
      productimage: "https://i.imgur.com/sJUpSpt.jpg",
      productname: "dummy1",
      productrating: 3
      }
```

---

code snippet for backend Spring RestAPI code is :

```
 @RestController
 public class OnlineShoppingController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping(path="/productslist",method =RequestMethod.POST)
    public Product createProduct(@Valid @RequestBody Product product) {
        return productService.createProduct(product);
    }

    }
```

where Product is dto/Entity object ie:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product_table")
public class Product {
    @Id

    @Column(name="productid", columnDefinition="INT(100)")
    private int  productid;

    @Column(name="productname")
    private String   productname;

    @Column(name="productcode")
    private String    productcode;

    @Column(name="productavaliabledate")
    private String  productavaliabledate;

    @Column(name="price" , columnDefinition="INT(100)")
    private int  price;

    @Column(name="productrating",  columnDefinition="INT(50)")
    private int  productrating;

    @Column(name="productimage")
    private String   productimage;

    //getter,setter,constructor using field are also provided
    }
```

Comment: Your frontend [is forbidden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) to call that service. Check your configuration, or maybe authorization.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Can you please provide the code snippet or any link which I can refer to.It will be help me allot.

Comment: Can *you* please provide a code snippet? You system is configured in a specific way which makes your code not work, and there is no configuration details in question. I cannot guess what the problem is.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Thanks for your suggestion. But I have no much configuration in my frontend code. While calling the post method I am setting the required Headers as shown in above code.
And in spring boot (backend code) Apart from application.properties where I have configure for MySql database there is no much configurations are done.

Comment: Try to disable `csrf` like this `http.csrf().disable()` in spring security or pass `csrf-token` with request header from `angular`

Comment: Thanks for comments and suggestion for this Question.I have figured out it was not the problem with my (frontend ) Angular code. Basically my (backend) spring boot application was not authorizing POST,PUT,DELETE Http method request. Soo I have just configured springboot as shown in my Answer tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was **problem with spring boot configuration** **not with Angular application**.As  403 Forbidden status means :
 *Response to a request from a client for a web page or it may indicate that the server can be reached and process the request but server has refused to take any further action.*

Finally I have added a class AppConfig which extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter and overriden a method addCorsMappings() in order to allow me the access for all the HTTP method request.

AppConfig.java-

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And In my application.properties file I have disable springs basic security ie-

```
security.basic.enabled=false
```

Thanks for all your suggestions and comments for this problem.